# Authentication for Passive user

Tags: python, algorithm, facebook-oauth

I am writing a piece of code in Python2.7. I want to **compare 2 users based on their Facebook accounts**. For that I would need a users information such as *Likes, Movies, Music, Books, Notes, Permissions, Checkins, Locations etc*.

The problem I face is that not all users have allowed full permissions to view their information, for that I can use oauth2.0, but then again that would be only for the current user of my site (active user), how can I get the above stated information for the passive user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the “passive” user is a friend of your active one, then you can request “[friends_](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/#user_friends_perms)”-permissions from the latter one for all fields that permit this. Of course, you’ll only get these information, if the friend has set their privacy settings so that apps are allowed to access them on behalf of their friends.

Apart from that, the only other way would be to have your active user send a [request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/) to the passive one, to invite them to use your app as well. When they accept that, you can request the same permissions on the user level from them as well, and start your comparison afterwards.

For privacy reasons, there are no other ways – and that is a good thing.